# incomplete manual app deletion when tablet under MDM control

Tags: ios, installation, enterprise, mdm, airwatch

I have an enterprise iOS app that is distributed through an MDM (AirWatch), for which part of our operating procedure is to manually delete the old app, then have the user manually install through Airwatch (Catalog app). I'm seeing odd behavior for some users where the old app appears to not be completely deleted. Does anyone know if Airwatch keeps hold of an app it looks after to the point that complete manual deletion is not possible?

EDIT - FURTHER INFO

specifically, it appears that a SQLite database I use in the app is not being deleted as expected when the user manually deletes the app under the MDM

Comment: You need to provide more information. What isn't deleted? It is normal for keychain items to remain, for example.

Comment: Thanks Paulw11 - good point - added

Comment: The fact that the app is installed by AirWatch should change anything. How long between deletion and re-installation?  Are the database files stored in an application group directory?

Comment: The database is stored in the documents directory under a standard bundle ID ownership (not group). The app is deleted then the user next downloads - so maybe a 10 seconds between

Comment: Deleting the app should delete the files then; perhaps because you are re-installing so soon ios doesn't delete the data because it thinks you deleted in error?  I have never seen this documented anywhere though. It would be best to change your code so that a delete/install was not required. In-place upgrades are the norm. Store an app version in user defaults and then you can detect if t is the first run of a new version and delete the database in code.  You can then simply have Airwatch push an update when required.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the reasoning and the info - I agree - a reinstall needs to be avoided